# calling store procedures within fast-csv asynchronously

Tags: mysql, node.js, csv, promise, knex.js

I am writing a backend API in node.js and need the functionality for users to be able to upload files with data and then calling stored procedures  for inserting data into MySQL. I'm thinking of using fast-csv as parser, however I am struggling with how to set up the call to stored procedure in csv stream. the idea is something like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var csv = require("fast-csv");
var stream1 = fs.createReadStream("files/testCsvFile.csv");

csv
  .fromStream(stream2, { headers: true })
  .on("data", function(data) {

   //CALL TO SP with params from "data"//

    numlines++;
  })
  .on("end", function() {
    console.log("done");
  });
```

In other parts of application I have set up routes as follows:

```
auth.post("/verified", async (req, res) => {
    var user = req.session.passwordless;
    if (user) {
      const rawCredentials = await admin.raw(getUserRoleCredentials(user));
      const { user_end, role } = await normalizeCredentials(rawCredentials);
      const user_data = { user_end, role };
      res.send(user_data);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(401);
    }
  });
```

..that is  - routes are written in async/await way with queries (all are Stored Procedures called) being defined as Promises.. I would like to follow this pattern in upload/parse csv/call SP for every line function

Comment: You can try my [scramjet framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) - using a map like in array you can use async functions on a stream.

Comment: Tkank you man, it seems this is just what I needed . . however I don't know where exactly to put this - - I checked exapmles but am still struggling  . . How do I loop the stream (from csv file), and use data from that stream as parameters in asnync defined Stored Porcedure?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, I made my [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) to handle such a use case with ease... Please correct me if I understood it wrong, but I understand you want to call the two await lines for every CSV row in the test.

If so, your code would look like this (updated to match your comment/answer):

```
var fs = require("fs");
var csv = require("fast-csv");
var stream1 = fs.createReadStream("files/testCsvFile.csv");
var {DataStream} = require("scramjet");

DataStream
    // the following line will convert any stream to scramjet.DataStream
    .from(csv.fromStream(stream2, { headers: true }))
    // the next lines controls how many simultaneous operations are made
    // I assumed 16, but if you're fine with 40 or you want 1 - go for it.
    .setOptions({maxParallel: 16})
    // the next line will call your async function and wait until it's completed
    // and control the back-pressure of the stream
    .do(async (data) => {
        const query = await queryBuilder({
          schema,
          routine,
          parameters,
          request
        }); //here we prepare query for calling the SP with parameters from data

        winston.info(query + JSON.stringify(data));
        const rawResponse = await session.raw(query); //here the query gets executed
        return data; // push each row - for testing only)
    })
    // next line will run the stream until end and return a promise
    .toArray()
    .then(fileRows => {
        console.log(fileRows);
        fs.unlinkSync(form.FileName); // remove temp file
        //process "fileRows" and respond
        res.end(JSON.stringify(fileRows)); // - for testing
    })
    .catch(e => {
        res.writeHead(500); // some error handling
        res.end(e.message);
    })
    ;
    // you may want to put an await statement before this, or call then to check
    // for errors, which I assume is your use case.
;
```

To answer your comment question - if you were to use an async function in the `on("data")` event - you would need to create an array of promises and await Promise.all of that array on stream `end` - but that would need to be done synchronously - so async function in an event handler won't do it.

In `scramjet` this happens under the hood, so you can use the function.

Comment: Hey  - Man - thank you for your answers - - however, I didn't get it to work

Comment: Hey  - Man - thank you for your answers - - however, I didn't get it to work, I have an csv with app 1000 records - than I want to call async function for calling SP,  it never makes it to the end . maybe I misconfigure something - - with your setting actually the stream never made it the whole way through - - I guess something doing wrong - - I believe my option is to go with csv-fast,  I believe this is doing what I need by adding two async function into .on event

Comment: Ok, try adding a line with `.catch(e => console.error(e.stack))` and check the console. Perhaps there's an error you're not seeing?

Comment: Thank you man for all your help, however, I am gonna use the solution I proposed in answer. File gets uploaded with formidable library, and then in the on.end event, the file gets parsed with fast-csv  - - - the only problem I see with it is that I am using async function (for calling SP that inserts data into mysql), so that the .on("end") event gets fired before all the calls to SP gets executed . . If you perhaps have any idea how this should be solved, please ..

Comment: As I wrote in the edit - you could build an array of Promise objects from your async  function, but that won't be that easy. Try the new version I pasted, this should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is doing the job for me - - can you please describe how to achive that with your framework - - I believe it should be done somehowe, I just need to configure it correctli

```
 //use fast-csv to stream data from a file
    csv
      .fromPath(form.FileName, { headers: true })
      .on("data", async data => {
        const query = await queryBuilder({
          schema,
          routine,
          parameters,
          request
        }); //here we prepare query for calling the SP with parameters from data

        winston.info(query + JSON.stringify(data));
        const rawResponse = await session.raw(query); //here the query gets executed
        fileRows.push(data); // push each row - for testing only
      })

      .on("end", function() {
        console.log(fileRows);
        fs.unlinkSync(form.FileName); // remove temp file
        //process "fileRows" and respond

        res.end(JSON.stringify(fileRows)) // - for testing
      });
```